# Getting the machine serial number and CPU ID using C/C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

How can I get the machine serial number and CPU ID in a Linux system?

Sample code is highly appreciated.

Comment: @viraptor , none of the hits on the 1. page have a real answer. This question is the 1. hit now, it'll be nice if it gets a real answer. That's one of the purposes of SO. To provide a canonical answer ot specific questions, without all the dead content of forums.

Comment: by 'Machine Serial number' do you mean the serial numbers of the CPUs or the motherboard serial number ?

Comment: @viraptor indeed very interesting. There are many upvotes on answers and one is even accepted, even if it does not at all reply to the question. I think I will downvote all of them and flag the question. Seriously this is ridiculous. Even Andre Holzner asked for clarification, then posted just something to join the point-race, then got accepted for a crap answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L173) is what the Linux kernel seems to use:

```
static inline void native_cpuid(unsigned int *eax, unsigned int *ebx,
                                unsigned int *ecx, unsigned int *edx)
{
        /* ecx is often an input as well as an output. */
        asm volatile("cpuid"
            : "=a" (*eax),
              "=b" (*ebx),
              "=c" (*ecx),
              "=d" (*edx)
            : "0" (*eax), "2" (*ecx));
}
```

which one then can use as e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned eax, ebx, ecx, edx;

  eax = 1; /* processor info and feature bits */
  native_cpuid(&eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);

  printf("stepping %d\n", eax & 0xF);
  printf("model %d\n", (eax >> 4) & 0xF);
  printf("family %d\n", (eax >> 8) & 0xF);
  printf("processor type %d\n", (eax >> 12) & 0x3);
  printf("extended model %d\n", (eax >> 16) & 0xF);
  printf("extended family %d\n", (eax >> 20) & 0xFF);

  /* EDIT */
  eax = 3; /* processor serial number */
  native_cpuid(&eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);

  /** see the CPUID Wikipedia article on which models return the serial 
      number in which registers. The example here is for 
      Pentium III */
  printf("serial number 0x%08x%08x\n", edx, ecx);

}
```

Where a good reference on how to use the `CPUID` instruction is in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID).

**EDIT** The Wikipedia article says that the serial number was introduced with the Pentium III but was not anymore implemented in later models due to privacy concerns. On a Linux system you can check for the presence of this feature (PSN bit) by doing:

```
grep -i --color psn /proc/cpuinfo
```

if this does not show anything, your system does not support a processor serial number.

Comment: The result of this call is not a "serial number". It is a non-unique identifier for the **model** of CPU that is installed in the computer (e.g, "Intel Xeon E5-2630").

Comment: indeed, of the Intel CPUs, only Pentium III seems to support it (and only if it is enabled in the BIOS). I updated the answer.

Answer (score 24):

There is a cpuinfo.h include in GCC. It is safe, use it.

Sample (I have GCC 4.7+ and feel happy of using "auto" here):

```
#include <cpuid.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct CPUVendorID {
    unsigned int ebx;
    unsigned int edx;
    unsigned int ecx;

    string toString() const {
        return string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(this), 12);
    }
};

int main() {
    unsigned int level = 0;
    unsigned int eax = 0;
    unsigned int ebx;
    unsigned int ecx;
    unsigned int edx;

    __get_cpuid(level, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);

    CPUVendorID vendorID { .ebx = ebx, .edx = edx, .ecx = ecx };

    map<string, string> vendorIdToName;
    vendorIdToName["GenuineIntel"] = "Intel";
    vendorIdToName["AuthenticAMD"] = "AMD";
    vendorIdToName["CyrixInstead"] = "Cyrix";
    vendorIdToName["CentaurHauls"] = "Centaur";
    vendorIdToName["SiS SiS SiS "] = "SiS";
    vendorIdToName["NexGenDriven"] = "NexGen";
    vendorIdToName["GenuineTMx86"] = "Transmeta";
    vendorIdToName["RiseRiseRise"] = "Rise";
    vendorIdToName["UMC UMC UMC "] = "UMC";
    vendorIdToName["Geode by NSC"] = "National Semiconductor";

    string vendorIDString = vendorID.toString();

    auto it = vendorIdToName.find(vendorIDString);
    string vendorName = (it == vendorIdToName.end()) ? "Unknown" : it->second;

    cout << "Max instruction ID: " << eax << endl;
    cout << "Vendor ID: " << vendorIDString << endl;
    cout << "Vendor name: " << vendorName << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
$ make
g++ --std=c++11 main.cc -o cpuid
$ ./cpuid 
Max instruction ID: 6
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
Vendor name: Intel
```

Answer (score 8):

The Informations about the processor you could extract from `/proc/cpuinfo`.

To get the Serial Number you should have a look at `dmidecode`. I didn't look in there right now, but `dmidecode` is able to show you the serial number, so i would start there.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getPSN(char *PSN)
{
    int varEAX, varEBX, varECX, varEDX;
    char str[9];
    //%eax=1 gives most significant 32 bits in eax 
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid"   : "=a" (varEAX), "=b" (varEBX), "=c" (varECX), "=d" (varEDX) : "a" (1));
    sprintf(str, "%08X", varEAX); //i.e. XXXX-XXXX-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
    sprintf(PSN, "%C%C%C%C-%C%C%C%C", str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], str[7]);
    //%eax=3 gives least significant 64 bits in edx and ecx [if PN is enabled]
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid"   : "=a" (varEAX), "=b" (varEBX), "=c" (varECX), "=d" (varEDX) : "a" (3));
    sprintf(str, "%08X", varEDX); //i.e. xxxx-xxxx-XXXX-XXXX-xxxx-xxxx
    sprintf(PSN, "%s-%C%C%C%C-%C%C%C%C", PSN, str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], str[7]);
    sprintf(str, "%08X", varECX); //i.e. xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-XXXX-XXXX
    sprintf(PSN, "%s-%C%C%C%C-%C%C%C%C", PSN, str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], str[7]);
}

int main()
{
     char PSN[30]; //24 Hex digits, 5 '-' separators, and a '\0'
     getPSN(PSN);
    printf("%s\n", PSN); //compare with: lshw | grep serial:
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This program will help you run Linux commands programmatically:

```
char* GetSystemOutput(char* cmd)
{
    int buff_size = 32;
    char* buff = new char[buff_size];

    char* ret = NULL;
    string str = "";

    int fd[2];
    int old_fd[3];
    pipe(fd);

    old_fd[0] = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
    old_fd[1] = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    old_fd[2] = dup(STDERR_FILENO);

    int pid = fork();
    switch(pid)
    {
        case 0:
               close(fd[0]);
               close(STDOUT_FILENO);
               close(STDERR_FILENO);
               dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
               dup2(fd[1], STDERR_FILENO);
               system(cmd);
               //execlp((const char*)cmd, cmd,0);
               close (fd[1]);
               exit(0);
               break;

        case -1:
               cerr << "GetSystemOutput/fork() error\n" << endl;
               exit(1);

        default:
               close(fd[1]);
               dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);

               int rc = 1;
               while (rc > 0)
               {
                   rc = read(fd[0], buff, buff_size);
                   str.append(buff, rc);
                   //memset(buff, 0, buff_size);
               }

               ret = new char [strlen((char*)str.c_str())];

               strcpy(ret, (char*)str.c_str());

               waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
               close(fd[0]);
    }

    dup2(STDIN_FILENO, old_fd[0]);
    dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, old_fd[1]);
    dup2(STDERR_FILENO, old_fd[2]);

    return ret;
}
```

API usage: `GetSystemOutput("/usr/bin/lsb_release -a")`

And following the commands:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo = tells you CPU information
```