# How can get I a hardware ID in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

I can't get the CPU ID or motherboard serial number in all operating system (cross platform [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29))

On Windows I'm using [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) and on Mac another. I want use a cross-platform library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although Qt detects at runtime the CPU feature set (cf. src/corelib/tools/qsimd.cpp), it does not export any function to access that (nor any other CPUID information). Write your small piece of assembly code to gather that information. - [source](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8287)

You will have to write some platform dependent code to retrieve this information.

For the CPU id you should probably look into the function [`__cpuid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for Windows and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491566/getting-machine-serial-number-and-cpu-id-using-c-c-in-linux) answer can help you out on getting it for Linux.

Doing this you might want to consider reading up on motherboard serial numbers as not all of them provide this information at the same place (most do not provide it at all).

Answer (score 2):

Qt 5.11 introduced this function: [QSysInfo::machineUniqueId](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsysinfo.html#machineUniqueId)

Answer (score -1):

You can execute this command :
"wmic cpu get ProcessorId"