# what is the right way to get processor vendor name in c?

Tags: c, processor

I would like to check if my processor is AMD or INTEL in C and do necessary action according to that.
What is the right and efficient way to get it in C?

Should i run system(linux command) or is there any other nice way to get it.

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14266772/656243

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6491566/656243

Answer (score 1):

Since You didn't point an OS you are working at here is how you do it for OSX

```
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
```

I think that in c it is the same library just called by `#include`
To use `uint64_t` type value you should include `<stdint.h>`

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

len=0;
uint64_t freq = 0; //

size_t size = sizeof(freq);
sysctlbyname("machdep.cpu.brand_string", NULL, &len, NULL, 0);
if(len) 
{
    sysctlbyname("machdep.cpu.brand_string", &freq, &len, NULL, 0);
}
```

The answer you will get will be stored in `freq`

To know the name of `sysctlbyname` you can run `sysctl -a` in terminal

I think that `sysctl` is also compatible with linux but I never test it on linux machine

http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3/sysctlbyname/

Comment: FYI, the OP called out linux in the last sentence. It wasn't definitive, but it's a good guess.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Yes you are right , but osx has some"linux commands" as well , also I am 80% sure it will work under linux machine as well , since it uses the GNU library

Comment: I thought the question was asking for the processor vendor name, not the L3 cache size. And I'll note that `*sizeof(char)` is never necessary, because `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition. Always.

Comment: @Fred Larson , yes you are right :-) fhanged the answer accordingly